# cordova build android fails on windows: temp dir not writable

Tags: android, cordova

I'm just starting learning cordova.
I set up the "hello" test app and tried to build it. However, I get a quite strange error message where I couldn't find a solution via google:

During cordova build android in gradle target ":app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug" it fails with:

> "WARNING: Directory T:\Temp\lambdas3746978893947448209 is not writable - dumping disabled"

(T:\Temp is my %TEMP%)

However, Temp is writable, but I noticed that the "lambdas..." dir wasn't created.

Some more log:

```
:app:extractTryWithResourcesSupportJarDebug
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebugM?r 03, 2018 12:26:26 PM java.lang.invoke.ProxyClassesDumper getInstance
WARNING: Directory T:\Temp\lambdas3746978893947448209 is not writable - dumping disabled
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to register lambda dump directory 'T:\Temp\lambdas3746978893947448209'
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:864)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.verifyLambdaDumpDirectoryRegistered(Desugar.java:593)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:578)

M?r 03, 2018 12:26:26 PM java.lang.invoke.ProxyClassesDumper getInstance
WARNING: Directory T:\Temp\lambdas7422877859898884802 is not writable - dumping disabled
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to register lambda dump directory 'T:\Temp\lambdas7422877859898884802'
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:864)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.verifyLambdaDumpDirectoryRegistered(Desugar.java:593)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:578) FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: I just realized that I can avoid this bug if I use the android@6.4.0 platform, not the current 7.0.0 (` cordova platform add "android@^6.4.0"`). I still use cordova@8.0.0

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes, for now I use cordova android@6.4.0. (Although I would call this "avoid" rather then "solve" ;-)) I think there is a new version out but I didn't try this. Maybe, I should answer the question, thanks for the reminder :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Star_Man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534531/android-gradle-building-error-in-ramdisk) I got the important hint: It doesn't work when using a ram disk (well, I use ImDisk, I don't know if it works with others).

So my solution is now that I set TMP to somewhere else on a physical disk and it compiles :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can *avoid* this bug if I use the **android@6.4.0 platform**, not the current 7.0.0 or 7.1.1 (`cordova platform add "android@^6.4.0"`). I works fine with cordova@8.0.0.

Comment: With cordova platform android@7.1.1 I still get the same error message. That's kind of annoying since I'd like to update to the current android in order to be able to support API level 27 (Android 8.1)