# Android gradle building error in ramdisk

Tags: android, gradle, ramdisk

I am using ramdisk in windows.

But when I use the windows temp folder in ramdisk, I see the following errors.
(Here 'M:\Temp\' is %TEMP% in windows)

Do I need more setting to use RAMDISK in windows 10?

```
app:checkManifestChangesDebug
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug
Jul 26, 2018 4:32:19 PM java.lang.invoke.ProxyClassesDumper getInstance
WARNING: Directory M:\Temp\lambdas6090245423481063565 is not writable - dumping disabled
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to register lambda dump directory 'M:\Temp\lambdas6090245423481063565'
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:864)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.verifyLambdaDumpDirectoryRegistered(Desugar.java:720)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:705)

Jul 26, 2018 4:32:19 PM java.lang.invoke.ProxyClassesDumper getInstance
WARNING: Directory M:\Temp\lambdas4100554892407528594 is not writable - dumping disabled
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to register lambda dump directory 'M:\Temp\lambdas4100554892407528594'
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:864)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.verifyLambdaDumpDirectoryRegistered(Desugar.java:720)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:705)

:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Thanks for your question - it helped my solving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083695/cordova-build-android-fails-on-windows-temp-dir-not-writable - which ram disk are you using? I fear that ImDisk I'm using misses some API features.