# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to register lambda dump directory

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic application, but I'm getting following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to register lambda dump directory '/tmp/lambdas3316777149735161712'
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:864)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.verifyLambdaDumpDirectoryRegistered(Desugar.java:593)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:578)
```

This is what I've tried so far:

- I made sure that the `/tmp/` directory is writable
- I also tried running `cordova platform add "android@^6.4.0"` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083695/cordova-build-android-fails-on-windows-temp-dir-not-writable) answer. (I'm not using ramdisk, btw)
- Run it in Mac
- Run it in Linux (Arch)

All those 4 gave me the exact same result.

Am I missing something?